Viewing RAW Photos from Canon RD500 in GIMP and RawTherapee
I'm encountering an issue with viewing RAW photos from my Canon RD500 in GIMP and RawTherapee. cant access or work with these files. I'm new inLunux I tried to download both GIMP and RawTherapee: Neither of these programs seems to recognize or display my photos
I tried adding UFRAW to my sources. However, still facing the same issue.
I've scoured forums and documentation but haven't found a definitive solution yet. Could anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue?

It may help if you provide Ubuntu product/release details, and what package type of GIMP is installed (ie. default version for your unstated Ubuntu product/release, or a snap package). Likewise the other app you mention. Have you queried the system as to what type of file is recognized (ie. file for example).

THE CR3 format is relatively recent and Canon never disclosed the technical details, so reverse-engineering took a while. It should be supported in recent RT versions (IIRC, about since 2023). Check that you have very recent versions of RT. If you are interested in photography using FOSS, pixls.us is where the fun happens (the RawTherapee and DarkTable developers hang out there).

operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, with GIMP installed as a snap package. As RawTherapee installed via flathub
I've performed some checks on the type of file recognized by the system, but it seems that they are still not correctly recognized. I'm still working on resolving this issue and appreciate any other advice

This is a Question & Answer site (not a forum) so please add additional details to your question (that is what will be answered, comments being intended for readers to ask or make comments on question, they'll get removed once addressed in question itself).  What output or type of file was provided when you queried the system as to what it was?  (ie. what did file say?  ASCII text or what?;  if unsure what I mean, you can use the file command to ask your OS what type of file it is; which will allow you to understand why system treat it the way it does)
